# how to solve "Ti is not defined in SqlLiteProxy.js" in Desktop Titanium?

Tags: titanium, sencha-touch

how to solve "Ti is not defined in SqlLiteProxy.js" in Desktop Titanium ?
Iam also getting "The 'sqlite' type has not been registered with this manager."

Iam a newbie to titanium.

Answer (score 0):

"Ti" variable works with mobile apps. you have to use "Titanium" for Desktop apps in Titanium in code.